# Look up value in dataframe and return value

Tags: r, dataframe, search, matrix, lookup

I'm not sure why I'm having difficulty finding an answer to what should be a simple problem. I have the following dataframe:

```
> test
     Month        Equity - Rank FI - Rank Alts - Rank Reweight
[1,] "2006-01-31" "1"           "3"       "2"         "No"    
[2,] "2006-02-28" "1"           "3"       "2"         "No"    
[3,] "2006-03-31" "1"           "3"       "2"         "No"    
[4,] "2006-04-28" "1"           "3"       "2"         "No"    
[5,] "2006-05-31" "2"           "3"       "1"         "No"    
[6,] "2006-06-30" "1"           "3"       "2"         "No"    
[7,] "2006-07-31" "2"           "3"       "1"         "No"    
[8,] "2006-08-31" "1"           "3"       "2"         "No"
```

All I want to do is search by "Month" and return the values for that row.

I've been trying the following but keep getting no result back:

```
test[test$Month == '2006-03-31',]
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Month               `Equity - Rank` `FI - Rank` `Alts - Rank` Reweight
  <dttm>                        <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: please provide your data with `dput()`

Comment: Your data frame is not a data frame, it's a matrix—you can see that all the dates and numbers have been coerced to strings. Make it a proper data frame, and this will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after more searching

```
> test[which(test2 == '2006-01-31'),]
        Month Equity - Rank     FI - Rank   Alts - Rank      Reweight 
 "2006-01-31"           "1"           "3"           "2"          "No"
```